# Gradle multi-project structure

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a next structure in my root project forlder:

```
- AndroidLibrary1
-- build.gradle
- Android.library2
-- build.gradle 
- Application
-- build.gradle
build.gradle
```

I know how i can build android-library and application. So i want to build separately and step-by-step all my android projects and after that build main root project(just a releasing(signifying logic) 
But how i can set dependency like an :

Application **->** AndroidLibrary2 **->** AndroidLibrary1 ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup your respective Gradle dependancies as follows;

Application -->

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':AndroidLibrary2')
}
```

AndroidLibrary2 -->

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':AndroidLibrary1')
}
```

Not sure if you have this already or not but this should setup the dependancy order you need.  Hope this helps.